# How to configure pfsense to use VPN as gateway for OPT port only?

Tags: vpn, vlan, pfsense, ipsec

Currently I have set up my PfSense SG-1100 to function as a site to site VPN.  I have an unused OPT port on my router and I want to attach that to a switch and have it function as the gateway to the site to site VPN.  Another way to describe the goal is that LAN port will provide the local network and OPT port will have IP addresses assigned from the VPN.

Is this even possible?

Thank you,

Devan